# Apache2 multiple domains to use same document root

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

Trying to get multiple domains (potentially dozens) to use the same document root as I want laravel to take care of all the routing.

Sites will be custom domain names ie. johnwilson.com, davidsmith.com, lisabrown.com and laravel will display a templated page. I do **not** want the URL rewritten in the address bar to the user.

I can't get apache2 to respect my virtual host configuration though, especially using SSL.

The configuration is a LAMP stack on Ubuntu. I have two other runrelated sites already running successfully on this server, using two seperate document roots. These are proxied through cloudfare.

These "templated" pages I'm just going to use lets encrypt for though.

I've tried:
2 seperate virtual hosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName johnsmith.com.au
    DocumentRoot /var/www/microsites/public
    # letsencrypt certificate details here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName lisabrown.com.au
    DocumentRoot /var/www/microsites/public
    # letsencrypt certificate details here
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case johnsmith.com.au works, but lisabrown.com.au just redirects to johnsmith.com.au. completely rewriting the url in the address bar.

I've tried using **ServerAlias** aswell but this leads me to various errors, 404, SSL_INSECURE.

What's the correct way to do this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Using the following conf files (one per domain) I got it to work as expected. (and deleting the letsencrypt auto generated domain-le-ssl.conf file)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com.au
    ServerAlias www.domain.com.au
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com.au [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com.au
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName domain.com.au
            ServerAdmin admin@domain.com.au
            DocumentRoot /var/www/microsites/public

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/microsites/domain.error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/microsites/domain.access.log combined

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com.au/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com.au/privkey.pem
            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```